# Is there a way to change the Gnome power off prompt so it has more option

Tags: gnome

When you click on "power off", you only get three options: cancel, power off and restart.

I was wondering if you can change it so there are more options like "suspend" or "log out" Like seen here

[image: like seen here]

Comment: Your version of Ubuntu??

Comment: GNOME by design will change the options when for example you hold down <ALT> or keys... I'm no fan of if, but it was seen as *clean* (many options; keeping it *clean & simple* is in).   Note: I'm going from memory; I'm not a GNOME user by choice.

Comment: I'm using 20.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can !

There is an extension available for Gnome

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3070/simpler-off-menu/

This enables, once installed, the suspend and hibernate options.

As @guiverc also pointed out in the comments, You can also change the function of some buttons while holding "ALT" in Gnome.

Answer (score 1):

You already see some workarounds in other answers. I just wanted to answer the actual question, whether you can change the dialog. No, not easily without editing source code.

The exit dialog is actually provided by the tool `gnome-session-quit`. Called without arguments, it will display the "Log Out" dialog. It can also be called with the options `--power-off` or `--reboot`. In Ubuntu It is not designed to present multiple options.

In Ubuntu 18.04, the `--power-off` option indeed also presents a "Restart" button. In later versions, also `--power-off` only does what it is designed to do: offer a "Power Off" prompt.

So no, there is no easy way to change the dialog. You would need to replace the `gnome-session-quit` binary with your own custom version, or change Gnome Shell (e.g. through a Gnome Shell extension) to call a custom dialog.

In the mean time, the options are available for mouse users in the user menu. Power users may find it faster to hit <kbd>super</kbd> then type "Shut", or "Rebo" or "Logo" then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to activate the respective option.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using Gnome. You may install the Gnome extension - [Bring Out Submenu Of Power Off/Logout Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2917/bring-out-submenu-of-power-offlogout-button/) for getting more options.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a custom launcher next to the power off button with the [Launcher extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5874/launcher/). It will add script or program directly in the menu.