# Can you configure the power button to bring up a shutdown options menu/

Tags: suspend, shutdown

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a laptop and I would like, when I press the power button, to see a menu of suspend/shutdown/restart options, rather than to immediately trigger a suspend/shutdown action. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not as such possible (unless perhaps with some deeper hacking). At most, you can have a dialog displayed that asks you confirmation before powering off (and only for powering off). This is because the tool that provides the dialog does not allow presenting multiple options. See more detail [in my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1347955/558158)).

Enabling a confirmation dialog (as indicated before, a confirmation for shutting down only) is not exposed in the "Settings" dialog. You can enable this with a `gsettings` command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'interactive'
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the question.